# format conversion not working in calculating fiscal year based on the month

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the fiscal year based on my month. The conversion is not working. Currently my time stamp is type `object`. I have converted it to int to get the necessary values it does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
upload_raw['Month_']= upload_raw['CREAT_TS'].str[:10]
upload_raw['Year_']= upload_raw['Month_'].str[:4].astype(int)

upload_raw['Month_']=pd.DatetimeIndex(upload_raw['Month_']).month.astype(int)
def year_conv():
    if upload_raw['Month_'] > 6: 
        upload_raw['Year_']+1
    else:
        upload_raw['Year_1']
```

I still get the same value as the year.

This is the format that i have for the date that i am converting it.

```
CREAT_TS
2018-06-22-06.48.49.601000
```

Entire Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pyodbc
import calendar

#loading Agency Notices Upload Raw Data
upload_raw = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Upload Raw Data.xlsx',
                     sheet_name = 'Upload',
                     header = 0
                     )
display(upload_raw)
upload_raw.dtypes
datatype =upload_raw.dtypes
display(datatype)

# creating Month and Year column
upload_raw['Month_']= upload_raw['CREAT_TS'].str[:10]
upload_raw['Year_']=upload_raw['Month_'].str[2:4].astype(int)
upload_raw['Month_']=pd.DatetimeIndex(upload_raw['Month_']).month.astype(int)

def year_conv():
    if upload_raw['Month_'] > 6: 
        upload_raw['Year_']+1
    else:
        upload_raw['Year_1']



upload_raw['Month_']=upload_raw['Month_'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])


# loading Branch Mapping Details
mapping = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Mapping.xlsx',
                     sheet_name = 'Mapping',
                     header = 0
                     )

upload_lookup= pd.merge(left = upload_raw, right= mapping,on='BRANCH')
display(upload_lookup)
```

Here is the sample data from the upload file

```
BRANCH  CUE CREAT_TS                     RAF_IND
AA      &CR 2018-06-22-06.48.49.601000  
AA      &CR 2018-06-22-11.43.29.859000  
AA      &CR 2018-06-22-11.54.52.633000  
AA      EZZ 2018-06-22-11.05.13.371000
```

From CREAT_TS i am trying to get the month and the YEAR. If the `month > 6` then the `year` should be `year+1` else should be the `year` that is present.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: so your 'Month_' variable is the first 10 characters of the string, in this case `2018-06-22`. You are asking python to determine whether `2018-06-22 > 6`. How do you expect the program to evaluate that?

Comment: @Andrew this part of the code is evaluating the same `upload_raw['Month_']=pd.DatetimeIndex(upload_raw['Month_']).month.astype(int)`

Comment: If you provide an example of your current dataframe and an example of the desired output, it will be much easier to help you. Slowly piecing together your problem in the comments section is not easy. [mcve]

Comment: @Andrew i have added my entire code and the sample of the raw data.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. What output are you expecting? in the example  df you provided, every month == 6, which means that month < 6 evaluates to False. I.E., none of these rows should change if your function works as expected

Comment: @Andrew If the Month > 6  then YEAR  (2017 +1) = 2018 else YEAR = 2017. Please note this is just a sample. so if my Month  df[2018-06-22-06.48.49.601000] = 9 the Year should be 2019

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179412/discussion-between-andrew-and-ren-lyke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using np.where()

Based on your example, I've created a simplified dataframe to demonstrate. Note that I changed the final month to 7, so that we have an example where your condition evaluates to True.

```
df
Out[74]: 
   Month_  Year_
0       6     18
1       6     18
2       6     18
3       7     18
```

to avoid confusion, I am saving the new variable in 'Years_' so you can see the change.

```
df['Years'] = np.where(df['Month_'] > 6, df['Year_'] + 1, df['Year_'])

df
Out[79]: 
   Month_  Year_  Years
0       6     18     18
1       6     18     18
2       6     18     18
3       7     18     19
```

Comment: I also would recommend you read the entire datetime section of the pandas docs. If you are trying to account for a fiscal year, there is already built-in functionality for that.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I searched the documentation specifically with the key word fiscal year or fiscal could not find it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.